# Multivariate central limit theorem and coefficient of variation

Tags: probability, central-limit-theorem

I'm trying to solve this problem:

*Let $\{X_i\}_{n \geq 1}$ i.i.d random variables with finite 4th-moment. Define:*

*$Y_n = {1 \over n}(X_1 + \cdots + X_n)$*

*$W_n = {1 \over n}(X_1^2 + \cdots + X_n^2)$*

*(a) Find the limit distribution of:*

*$\sqrt{n} \left(\left(
           \begin{matrix}
           Y_n \\
           W_n \\
           \end{matrix}\right) - \boldsymbol{\mu} \right)$*

*for an appropriate vector $\boldsymbol{\mu}$.*

*(b) Use the Delta Method for finding the limit distribution of:*

*$\sqrt{n} \left(\left(
           \begin{matrix}
           Y_n \\
           W_n - Y_n^2
           \end{matrix}\right) - \boldsymbol{\lambda} \right)$*

*for an appropriate vector $\boldsymbol{\lambda}$.*

*(c) Use the previous results to find the limit distribution of the coefficient of variation given by: $\sqrt{W_n - Y_n^2} \over Y_n$*

I've been assuming that $E(X_1) = 0$, $E(X_1^2)=Var(X_1)=\sigma^2$.

For part (a) I found that for $\boldsymbol{\mu} = \left(
           \begin{matrix}
           0 \\
           \sigma^2 \\
           \end{matrix}\right)$ you just need to find the matrix
 $\Sigma = \left(              \begin{matrix}
           Var(Y_n) \quad Cov(Y_n, W_n) \\
           Cov(Y_n, W_n) \quad Var(W_n) \\
           \end{matrix}\right)$ and then use the central limit theorem. But I haven't been able to prove that $\Sigma$ is actually a constant matrix because the covariance part seems to depend on $n$.

Part (b) seems to be direct if you use the function $g(x,y) = (x, y - x^2)$. But again you need the matrix $\Sigma$.

And I havent't figured out how to use these results for part (c).

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Your plan looks OK to me, but you are looking at the covariance matrix of the sample averages $(Y_n,W_n)$ not of the summands $(X_n,X_n^2)$ as I suspect your sources on the central limit theorem suggest.  Of course the  two are off by  a multiplicative factor only, so the damage is easy to repair.  Your objection that  $Cov(Y_n,W_n)$ depends on $n$ is a symptom of this, but it also holds for the upper left matrix entry $Var(Y_n)$, too.

Comment: I see your point. I'll give it another try using the covariance matrix for the summands $(X_n, X_n^2)$. Thanks a lot!